# Rails 5: jQuery not running with TurboLinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using Rails 5 and on flash messages I have an x icon when clicked closes the flash message.

Here is the JS function for it (located in `app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js`):

```
$(document).on("turbolink:load", function() {
  $('.close .icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  });
});
```

That JS function will not work. However when I copy and paste that function into the console, then press the x icon, it works.

Here's my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require semantic-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get that functionality to work?

Comment: The event is [`"turbolinks:load"`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads), not `"turbolink:load"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an 's' it is `turbolinks`.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.close .icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  });
});
```